# how to make the program pinned to the taskbar, which is in VS2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Good afternoon. I have such a problem. I need my program to pin itself to the taskbar. I've already crawled through almost the entire Internet, but I haven't found anything. Maybe someone knows how to do it through the code or some installer?

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to pin a console program to the taskbar when it's running in debug mode in VS 2022?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/pin-to-taskbar

Comment: ... or perhaps you are looking for "toast notifications"?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-notifications-overview

Comment: @Bellrampion no, I use wpf

Comment: @RobertHarvey could you tell me what to write in the places where there are comments?

Comment: @KaneJons: The article I linked describes this process in detail, including sample code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm sorry, but there is a conditional operator with comments. And then there is the announcement of a change in a separate paragraph.

Comment: The comments are there to tell you why you might want to put some code there.  You'll have to decide if it's appropriate to write code there, and what that code would be.  If it were me, I would use the code in Section 1 to check whether the required APIs exist, use the code in Section 2 to check whether taskbar is present and allows pinning, use the code in Section 3 to check whether the app is already pinned to the taskbar, and if all that succeeds, use the code in Section 4 to request pinning.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm sorry, but you don't have a section for 4, how exactly to fix it right away, for example, after the first launch of the program?